# searching string in 2d array python moving right or down

Tags: python, arrays, list, search

I have an array that contains strings, like this:

```
l = ["abc",
     "def",
     "hij",
     "klm",
     "nop",
     "qrs"]
```

and another one with words:

```
word = ["abc","knq","knop"]
```

What I need to find the word in the list and return the respecting coordinates.

The particularity is that the searching must be in horizontal or vertical or together.

For examples the first word:

`abc` return the index `[(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)]`

`knq` return `[(3,0)(4,0)(5,0)]`

`knop` return `[(3,0)(4,0),(4,1),(4,2)]`

The char in the string are not unique and I need to save the movement for example move one char down or move one char right.
is not a diagonal word finder.

Comment: Arrays are something entirely different in Python. Please remove reference to them.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing characters have to be directly connected. You save the indices of each character in `l` in a dict, where key is the character and value is a list of indices tuples. Then you could loop through the words in `word` and do something like DFS from each position in the list of word's first character (going right or down). An example (follow the comments):

```
l = ["abc",
     "def",
     "hij",
     "klm",
     "nop",
     "qrs"]
word = ["abc","knq","knop"]

# save the indices of each character
indices = {}
for i, w in enumerate(l):
    for j, c in enumerate(w):
        indices[c] = indices.get(c, []) + [(i, j)]
def check(i, j, k, cur, w, tmp):
    # if current word matches return the list of indices
    if cur == w:
        return tmp
    # otherwise return false if we reach either end of l
    if i == len(l) or j == len(l[i]):
        return False

    # if the current position is inside l and the character maches the k'th character of w
    if l[i][j] == w[k]:
        # add the current character and appent it's position to tmp
        cur += l[i][j]
        tmp.append((i, j))
        # check the next position either right or down
        chk1 = check(i+1, j, k+1, cur, w, tmp)
        if (chk1):
            return chk1
        chk2 = check(i, j+1, k+1, cur, w, tmp)
        if (chk2):
            return chk2
    return False

# loop through each word and then through each position of the first character
for w in word:
    for idx in indices[w[0]]:
        # if word is found print the indices and break
        chk = check(idx[0], idx[1], 0, '', w, [])
        if chk:
            print(w, chk)
            break
```

output

```
abc [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
knq [(3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)]
knop [(3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]
```

Comment: that's what i'm looking for, but if i need to do it without global variables, how did you avoid the declaration of global ans

Comment: Check the edited code, got rid of the global ans

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of words and build those type of list repeatedly, I would build a translation dictionary first:

```
tr = dict()
for r,w in enumerate(l):
    for c,ch in enumerate(w):
        tr[ch] = (r,c)
```

Having that, you can easily create the lists with a list comprehension:

```
for w in word:
    res = [tr[ch] for ch in w]
    print(w)
    print(res)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abc
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]
knq
[(3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)]
knop
[(3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2)]
```

Comment: What happens with repeated letters?

Comment: No problem, if the are in `word`

Comment: Yes there is a problem, given your current dictionary only the last position is going to be recorded, then missing paths. In addition your solution does not checkt if the path is valid

Comment: OP is a bit vague in that regard. I assumed repeated letters only in the words in `word`. For that, it's fine. If there is a requrement, that also the characters of the strings in `l` must be repeated, then you are right. As nobody seems to be interested in the solution anyhow, I don't mind.